# Как сделать 2 Scanner?

Tags: java, scanner

Подскажите, почему не получается использовать 2ой Scanner

```
package n4;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class n4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double inputY,inputZ;
    Scanner     varForScan = null;
    Scanner     varForScan1 = null;     
    varForScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите число double: ");
    inputY = varForScan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Было задано число: "+inputY);
    varForScan.close();
    varForScan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Задайте еще одно значение типа double:");
    inputZ = varForScan1.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Было задано число: "+inputZ);
    varForScan1.close();

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете два сканнера, но один поток ввода информации: в обоих конструкторах вы указали `System.in`.

Вот все возможные варианты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`System.in` это как раз `InputStream` (как выделено на картинке)

Правда, не совсем понятно, зачем вы создаете еще один сканнер, если можно продолжать считывать первым?

На вашем же примере:

```
double inputY, inputZ;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Введите число double: ");

inputY = scanner.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Было задано число: " + inputY + "\nЗадайте еще одно значение типа double:");

System.out.println();

inputZ = scanner.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Было задано число: " + inputZ);
scanner.close();
```

После этого в `inputY` запишется первое введенное значение, а в `inputZ` второе.

---

Вы настойчиво требуете, что вам нужен ещё один сканнер - хорошо, тогда просто уберите строчку `varForScan.close();` и всё будет работать. Почему? потому что при закрытии сканнера закрывается и поток ввода, а уже после этого вы пытаетесь вторым сканнером считать информацию с уже закрытого потока, и у вас вылетает ошибка.

Comment: @batqr а что вы хотите? Какой нужен результат?

Comment: @batqr дополнил ответ.

Comment: @batqr вы можете объяснить, зачем вам два сканнера?

Comment: @batqr дополнил ответ, описал почему у вас ошибка возникает, и как ее убрать.

Comment: Я попробую как вы предложили. Думаю подойдет.Спасибо Нужно было потому что, нужно было делать new scanner. Думал перед new нужно закрыть было предидущий.